# list of colors in a pie chart with variable number of slices

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgf-pie

Based on several codes found here and there on this forum, I built a simple code for creating a pie chart with a variable number of slices, see below. Right now, I am able to make the color of slices using shades of a main color defined in line 7. I am looking for a way to define in a list the colors I would like to use for each slice. Something like:

```
\def\mycolors{{"red","blue","green","yellow","","",""}}
```

but I cannot seem to find a way to properly read this list within my `\foreach` loop... Is there a way to do this ?

[image: my automated pie chart]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
% couleurs
\definecolor{main}{RGB}{185,30,50}
% 
% paramètres du graphique
\def\theme{main}
\newcommand\shares{{57,40,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}%
\def\commentaires{{"très satisfait","satisfait","peu satisfait","","","","","",""}}
\def\titre{niveau de satisfaction}
\def\nbcategories{3}
% 
% code
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \node[black,fill=none] at (0,2.5) {\titre};
    %
    \edef\startangle{0}%
    \draw[\theme!95!black, line width=1pt] (0,0) circle (2.05cm);
    \foreach [
        remember=\endangle as \startangle,
        evaluate=\i as \endangle using {\startangle+(\shares[\i-1]/100*360)},
        evaluate=\halfangle using {(\endangle-\startangle)/2+\startangle},] 
        \i in {1,...,\nbcategories} 
        {%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\intensite{(\nbcategories-\i)/(\nbcategories-1)*100}
        \fill[{\theme!\intensite}] (0,0) --++(\startangle:2cm) arc (\startangle:\endangle:2cm);
        \draw[white, line width=0.25mm](0,0)--++(\startangle:2cm+0.1pt);
    }%
    \draw[white,line width=0.25mm](0,0)--++(\startangle:2cm);%
    \fill[white](0,0)circle [radius=2cm*0.65];%    
    %
    \foreach [
        remember=\endangle as \startangle,
        evaluate=\i as \endangle using {\startangle+(\shares[\i-1]/100*360)},
        evaluate=\halfangle using {(\endangle-\startangle)/2+\startangle},] 
        \i in {1,...,\nbcategories} {%
        \node[\theme!65!black] at (\halfangle:2cm*0.475) {\textbf{\small\pgfmathparse{\shares[\i-1]}\pgfmathresult\%}};
    }%   
    %
    \foreach [] \i in {1,...,\nbcategories} {%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\intensite{(\nbcategories-\i)/(\nbcategories-1)*100}
        \draw[fill={\theme!\intensite},draw=black!65] (-2,-2.25-\i*0.35) -- (-1.75,-2.25-\i*0.35) -- (-1.75,-2.5-\i*0.35) -- (-2,-2.5-\i*0.35) -- cycle;
        \node[right] at (-1.75,-2.375-\i*0.35) {\small \pgfmathparse{\commentaires[\i-1]}\pgfmathresult\phantom{bp}};
    }%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a very low-key solution, but for a quick fix, everything you need is already there. Just define colours with a running number and then call then using the index, you are cycling through anyway.

Here are possible colour definitions (which are totally random, just for proof-of-principle):

```
\definecolor{category1}{RGB}{125,135,197}
\definecolor{category2}{RGB}{0,135,197}
\definecolor{category3}{RGB}{125,0,197}
\definecolor{category4}{RGB}{125,135,0}
\definecolor{category5}{RGB}{125,0,0}
\definecolor{category6}{RGB}{0,0,197}
\definecolor{category7}{RGB}{0,135,0}
\definecolor{category8}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{category9}{RGB}{255,255,255}
```

And then replace `\theme!\intensite` by `category\i` as your index is `\i`.

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
% couleurs
\definecolor{main}{RGB}{185,30,50}
% 
% paramètres du graphique
\def\theme{main}
\newcommand\shares{{11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11}}%
\def\commentaires{{"très satisfait","satisfait","peu satisfait","x","y","z","a","b","c"}}
\def\titre{niveau de satisfaction}
\def\nbcategories{9}

\definecolor{category1}{RGB}{125,135,197}
\definecolor{category2}{RGB}{0,135,197}
\definecolor{category3}{RGB}{125,0,197}
\definecolor{category4}{RGB}{125,135,0}
\definecolor{category5}{RGB}{125,0,0}
\definecolor{category6}{RGB}{0,0,197}
\definecolor{category7}{RGB}{0,135,0}
\definecolor{category8}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{category9}{RGB}{255,255,255}
% 
% code
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \node[black,fill=none] at (0,2.5) {\titre};
        %
        \edef\startangle{0}%
        \draw[\theme!95!black, line width=1pt] (0,0) circle (2.05cm);
        \foreach [
        remember=\endangle as \startangle,
        evaluate=\i as \endangle using {\startangle+(\shares[\i-1]/100*360)},
        evaluate=\halfangle using {(\endangle-\startangle)/2+\startangle},] 
        \i in {1,...,\nbcategories} 
        {%
            \pgfmathsetmacro\intensite{(\nbcategories-\i)/(\nbcategories-1)*100}
            \fill[{category\i}] (0,0) --++(\startangle:2cm) arc (\startangle:\endangle:2cm);
            \draw[white, line width=0.25mm](0,0)--++(\startangle:2cm+0.1pt);
        }%
        \draw[white,line width=0.25mm](0,0)--++(\startangle:2cm);%
        \fill[white](0,0)circle [radius=2cm*0.65];%    
        %
        \foreach [
        remember=\endangle as \startangle,
        evaluate=\i as \endangle using {\startangle+(\shares[\i-1]/100*360)},
        evaluate=\halfangle using {(\endangle-\startangle)/2+\startangle},] 
        \i in {1,...,\nbcategories} {%
            \node[\theme!65!black] at (\halfangle:2cm*0.475) {\textbf{\footnotesize\pgfmathparse{\shares[\i-1]}\pgfmathresult\%}};
        }%   
        %
        \foreach [] \i in {1,...,\nbcategories} {%
            \pgfmathsetmacro\intensite{(\nbcategories-\i)/(\nbcategories-1)*100}
            \draw[fill={category\i},draw=black!65] (-2,-2.25-\i*0.35) -- (-1.75,-2.25-\i*0.35) -- (-1.75,-2.5-\i*0.35) -- (-2,-2.5-\i*0.35) -- cycle;
            \node[right] at (-1.75,-2.375-\i*0.35) {\small \pgfmathparse{\commentaires[\i-1]}\pgfmathresult\phantom{bp}};
        }%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you could use the colours provided by the `colorbrewer` library and then try to cycle through your index and the given alphabetical colour indices, but that would require some more elaborate changes of your code.

Comment: Thank you, this works indeed !

Answer (score 1):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The gap between the slices is obtained with the key `gap`.

The percentages are given by `inner data=\WCperc`.

The legend is determined by the key `legend`. This is a `tabular` which is placed in a `\node`. The rows are determined by the key `legend row`. The result of all rows can be obtained with `\WClegend`.

The macro `\WClistcolors` refers to items in the list given to the key `WClistcolors`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  counterclockwise,
  data=,
  gap=0.03,
  inner data=\WCperc,
  inner data sep=0.3,
  legend row={\tikz\fill[\WClistcolors,draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (0.3,0.3); & \WCvarB},
  legend={
    \node[anchor=north] at (0,-3.5) {%
      \begin{tabular}{l@{ }l}%
      \WClegend%
      \end{tabular}%
    };
  },
  slices style=\WClistcolors,
  start angle=0,
  title=niveau de satisfaction,
  WClistcolors={green,orange,red}
]{%
  57/très satisfait,
  40/satisfait,
  3/peu satisfait%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```